# How does search works in hashing when items are stored as linked list by chaining?

Tags: hashtable, hash-collision

One way to deal the collision in hash tables is by chaining. Chaining store the collided items in a link list. But when a user search with a key how does hash table identify the item?

Answer (score 2):

1) The key is hashed to arrive at a hash bucket.

```
int hashKey = key.hashCode();
```

2) Everything in this bucket is chained in a linked list. We can iterate it until we find one element that matches the key. For every entry in the linked list,

```
if (key.equals(entry.getKey()) { return entry.getValue(); }
```

The second step is a plain linear search.

Hashtables only work properly if these chains don't get long, so you have to size the table large enough (and choose a decently hashable key) to avoid/minimize collisions.

Comment: So is this handled through double hashing ?

Comment: No. It's not hashed again. It just calls `equals` on the two keys (the one you want and the one in the bucket list). Plain linear search.

Answer (score 1):

The hash table compares your key against each key in the linked list that matches the hash of your key.

Comment: What you are saying is called double hashing isn't it?

Comment: No, you are not generating another hashcode for your key. 

Say keys k1 and k2 generate the same hashcode h1. The hashtable will have a list for hashcode h1 with both k1 and k2.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, by linearly searching the chain for the element.
The hash function generates the `head` of the chain.

To be more precise this works in Theta(1+l) where l is the load factor, faster compared to linear normal linear search of O(n)